# Content security policy error in href tag, but works fine on inline event handlers

Tags: javascript, webforms, content-security-policy, nonce

I have asp.net webforms project. My content security policy header is as follows

```
default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' data:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';img-src * 'self' data:;font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com data:;frame-src * data: blob: js: javascript:;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  'nonce-random123' 'strict-dynamic'; frame-ancestors 'self';worker-src 'self' blob: ;  script-src-attr  'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
```

In my page, all the inline html scripts works properly, like

```
<body onload="javascript:"> <input type="submit" onclick="javascript: ">
```

but, if I use

```
<a href="javascript:webpostback()">
```

, it throws error in console 'Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:'. Why it throws error on href, but not on other event handlers, Is there any    to avoid it.

Note: I have no control over the generated inline-scripts. Because the project is on webforms

**Console error:** Hello.aspx?A686142D6EC3F5E2=BD6AB64D03BB016326187CE1819DFD28:1 Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  'nonce-73cfe2af-3129-4148-98eb-c0e6e442c1f0' 'strict-dynamic'". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.

Comment: Best solution: avoid inline handlers entirely, they're quite terrible and have no reason to be used in modern JS

Comment: It would help if you could include the entire console error (remove possible sensitive parts) and give the results from testing with various browsers as CSP implementations differ.

Answer (score 1):

An `'unsafe-hashes'` token [should be paired](https://csplite.com/csp149/) with `'hash-value'` tokens of all inline event handlers and javascript:-navigations intended to be allowed. For example, to allow `<a href="javascript:webpostback()">` you have to use [hash](https://csplite.com/csp/sha/?pl=eJxLtDK0qi62MrFS8gjx9VGyLrYyNrVSsklUyChKTbNVykosSyxOLsosKLEqT00qyC8uSUpMztbQVLJTsq4FACtlExQ%3D#result):

```
script-src-attr 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-9X0thXkX9FwOrSOPpwOgHBUeXkoM5C9BR3EfKcuXYZg=';
```

Note 1: `'self'` and `'unsafe-eval'` is [not supported](https://csplite.com/csp111/#sources) in the `script-src-attr`.
Note 2: `'unsafe-inline'` cannot be paired with 'unsafe-hashes' since `'hash-value'` cancels `'unsafe-inline'`.

> Why it throws error on href, but not on other event handlers

It's strange. Chrome browser [supports](https://csplite.com/csp/test173/#Chrome) `'unsafe-hashes'` token for both of above. With CSP you showed, the Chrome should throw errors and for inline event handlers and for JS-navigation.
The only thing Chrome has a [bug](https://csplite.com/csp/test339/) with wrong definition of violated directive in javascript:-navigation. JS:-navigation is covered by the `script-src-attr` directive. But as you can see in your console error, Chrome shows the violation occured in the `script-src` despite you have `script-src-attr` in the CSP.

Firefox browser [supports](https://csplite.com/csp/test173/#Firefox) `'unsafe-hashes'` for inline event handlers (with a bug), but does not support `'unsafe-hashes'` for javascript:-navigations.

Safari does [not support](https://csplite.com/csp/test173/#Safari) `'unsafe-hashes'` at all.

Threrefore currently it's only one way to use `'unsafe-hashes'`:

```
script-src 'unsafe-inline'; script-src-attr 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-...' 'sha256-...';
```

Chrome will follow `script-src-attr` directive, other browsers do not support it and will use `'unsafe-inline'` from the `'script-src'`.
Chrome users will be much safe, but you cannot use `'nonce-value'` / `'hash-value'` / `'strict-dynamic'` tokens, because those override `'unsafe-inline'`.